# SqlAlchemy groupby of a union subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to do 3 queries on the same table, union them and then do a groupby with sum.

This is my solution.

```
q1 = Contact.query.with_entities(Contact.name, Contact.surname, Contact.company, literal(1).label('weight')).filter(Contact.name.ilike(expr))
q2 = Contact.query.with_entities(Contact.name, Contact.surname, Contact.company, literal(2).label('weight')).filter(Contact.surname.ilike(expr))
q3 = Contact.query.with_entities(Contact.name, Contact.surname, Contact.company, literal(3).label('weight')).filter(Contact.company.ilike(expr))

qq = q1.union_all(q2,q3).subquery()

w = db.session.query(qq.c.name, qq.c.surname, qq.c.company, func.sum(qq.c.weight)).group_by(qq.c.name).all()
```

It raise the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 210, in __getattr__

    return self._data[key]

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app

    response = self.handle_exception(e)

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise

    raise value

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise

    raise value

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/app/routes_contact.py", line 42, in contact

    w = db.session.query(qq.c.name, qq.c.surname, qq.c.company, func.sum(qq.c.weight)).group_by(qq.c.name).all()

    File "/home/user1/pyweb/profc/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 212, in __getattr__

     [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] raise AttributeError(key)

    AttributeError: name
```

Where am I wrong?

*** edit: SOLVED ***

The problem was the name after the union, I solved labeling every column

```
q1 = Contact.query.with_entities(Contact.name.label('uname'), Contact.surname.label('usurname'), Contact.company.label('ucompany'), literal(1).label('weight')).filter(Contact.name.ilike(expr))
q2 = Contact.query.with_entities(Contact.name.label('uname'), Contact.surname.label('usurname'), Contact.company.label('ucompany'), literal(2).label('weight')).filter(Contact.surname.ilike(expr))
q3 = Contact.query.with_entities(Contact.name.label('uname'), Contact.surname.label('usurname'), Contact.company.label('ucompany'), literal(3).label('weight')).filter(Contact.company.ilike(expr))

qq = q1.union_all(q2,q3).subquery()

w = db.session.query(qq.c.uname, qq.c.usurname, qq.c.ucompany, func.sum(qq.c.weight)).group_by(qq.c.uname).all()
```

Comment: on which line? provide a full traceback please

Comment: post edited with full error

Comment: Experimenting in the debugger  suggests that the column names are aliased, perhaps to  something like `contact_name`, `contact_surname` etc, where `contact` is the name of the _table_.  The docs say the aliasing scheme is deterministic, but do not promise any particular scheme, so it may be different for you.

Comment: I find the solution and edit the post with corrected code